# Drawing direction cosines with tike-3dplot

Tags: arrows, tikz-3dplot

I am trying to reproduce the following image using tikz-3dplot. 
[image]

I need help with the arrow heads of the vectors, the angles made with vector v and the unit vectors, i, j, and k.

Here is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
    \tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{110}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,tdplot_main_coords,font=\footnotesize,scale=1.5]
            \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
            \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,2,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
            \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,2) node[anchor=south]{$z$};
            \draw[thick,->,color=red,opacity=0.5] (0,0,0) -- (2.5,2.5,3) node[ right] {$\vec{v}$};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,angles,quotes}
\begin{document}
    \tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{110}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,tdplot_main_coords,font=\footnotesize,scale=1.5]
            \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0)coordinate (O) -- (3,0,0) coordinate (X)
                    node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
            \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,3,0) coordinate (Y) node[anchor=north
                    west]{$y$};
            \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,3) coordinate (Z) node[anchor=south]{$z$};
            \draw[thick,->,color=red,opacity=0.5] (0,0,0) -- (2.5,2.5,3) coordinate (V)
                    node[ right] {$\vec{v}$};
            \draw[dashed,magenta!50] (2.5,2.5,3) -- (2.5,2.5,0) -- (0,0,0);
            \draw[very thick,red!80!black,-{Triangle[fill=white]}] (0,0,0) --
                    (2,0,0)node [right=1ex] {$\mathbf{i}$};
            \draw[very thick,red!80!black,-{Triangle[fill=white]}] (0,0,0) --
                    (0,2,0)node [below] {$\mathbf{j}$};
            \draw[very thick,red!80!black,-{Triangle[fill=white]}] (0,0,0) --
                    (0,0,2)node [left] {$\mathbf{k}$};
            \path pic[draw, angle radius=5mm,"$\alpha$",angle
                    eccentricity=1,anchor=north east,inner sep=5pt] {angle
                     = X--O--V};
            \path pic[draw, angle radius=7mm,"$\beta$",angle
                    eccentricity=1.3,] {angle
                     = Y--O--V};
            \path pic[draw, angle radius=3mm,"$\gamma$",angle
                    eccentricity=1.5] {angle
                     = V--O--Z};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want `i` `j` `k` in black, add `text=black` to node options.